# How to migrate windows guest from XenServer 6.5 to Virtualbox (latest)

Tags: virtualization, migration, virtualbox, xenserver

Does anyone know the simplest way to migrate a Windows 10 Pro (x64) guest from a XenServer 6.5 host to Virtualbox?  XenServer is proving to be very difficult to manage for this setup, which is to simply host a couple of Windows guests for remote access use.  I think running these guests in Virtualbox on a linux host would make the administration a lot easier.

I'm thinking that it might work to use a hard drive backup tool to make a full system image within the existing guest OS, then boot a new Virtualbox instance from the backup tool's bootable recovery media, then restore the backup.  As long as the recovery software supports restoration to different hardware, this should work... but is there an easier way? i.e. export the existing guest's hard drive image to a VMDK or similar file?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Taking a disk image should work for HVM...if it's PV you cannot migrate it at all. But I think you can't install Windows 10 as a Xen PV guest, only HVM.

Comment: THX For your fast reply!  XenCenter: Virtualization Mode shows that it's HVM.

Comment: Right, so the image ought to boot OK in another hypervisor, possibly with a detour through Startup Repair...

Comment: That's great news.  I'm trying it now!

Comment: For the record, it worked!